# list comprehension with some equal action python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have such logic:

```
for need in we_need_this:
     items_dict[need] = to_string_and_select(need)
```

How can I do list comprehension?
i tried:

```
 [items_dict[need] = to_string_and_select(need) for need in we_need_this]
```

but it does`t work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with empty `items_dict`, simple dict comprehension will be enough.

```
items_dict = {x: to_string_and_select(x) for x in we_need_this}
```

In case `items_dict` is not empty, you'll need to update it using [`update`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method:

```
items_dict.update({x: to_string_and_select(x) for x in we_need_this})
```

On Python 2.6 and older use `dict((x, to_string_and_select(x)) for x in we_need_this)` instead of dict comprehension.

There're ugly ways to achieve this using list comprehension

```
from operator import setitem
[setitem(items_dict, x, to_string_and_select(x)) for x in we_need_this]
```

or

```
[items_dict.__setitem__(x, to_string_and_select(x)) for x in we_need_this]
```

Comment: +1 though its probably appropriate to note this method only works in python2.7+ ... for python2.6 or lower use `dict([(k,v) for k,v in some_list])` (which should also work in 2.7 +)

Answer (score 2):

Since `items_dict` is a dictionary, use `items_dict.update` and dict comprehension:

```
items_dict.update({
    need: to_string_and_select(need) for need in we_need_this
})
```